# European PS2 controller on american ps2

Tags: controllers, ps2

I bought and european PS2 controller (S.O.G brand), it does not work on my american PS2. Why and how to bypass that?

I have tested on an european PS2 and it works...

Thank you!

EDIT:
This is the exact model:

http://www.amazon.fr/Spirit-Gamer-SOG-WPG-Ordinateur-PlayStation/dp/B00TY7Z3BQ/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448174471&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=sog+mannette+ps2

As you can see it's not an official playstation controller. Maybe this model/brand is region lock...

Comment: Of course a controller will work with its correct console. What gave you the expectation that it would work on a foreign console?

Comment: What gives you the expectation that it should not work on a foreign console, @Frank? All references I can find state the ps2 controllers are not regon locked in any way, and there are reports of people buying them from across the world and using them successfully.

Comment: @Timelord See, now *there's* an expectation. If someone states that something doesn't work without adding in why they expect it should work, its a reasonable assumption that it's not supposed to.

Comment: @Frank, I agree, but I also think it works both ways. I would think it was common sense that it should work. I only went looking because I figured you knew something I didn't.

Comment: @Timelord64 We came at it from opposite ends. Based on current systems, I wouldn't expect periphials to work between regions, even if they're for the same console.